# Python SQLite - Update Not running

Tags: python, sqlite

I'm running a python script to run a SQLite code, which is successful until I get a specific Update query (create, inserts, drops run successfully).

Please note that this same code runs successfully in SQLiteExpert and when I run it in python there is no error message, the scripts simply does not pass that line and runs indefinitely.

I've looked into the documentation and searched for answers but I had no success. Wonder if anyone might help me with this one.

```
import sqlite3 

# Some more code 


conn.commit()

c.execute("""UPDATE TABEL_A SET FIELD_2 =
(SELECT FIELD_X FROM TABEL_B B WHERE B.FIELD_Y = FIELD_1)
 WHERE FIELD_3 = "A";""")

conn.commit()
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `FIELD_3 = "A"` wrong quotes

Comment: Tks Mat, but does does not make a difference, I've tried with 'A' and got the same result. Additionally, in other queries, with double quotes, it runs.

Comment: Show the table definitions.

Answer (score 0):

Update on the subject:

I was only able to solve the problem replacing the UPDATE approach to a CREATE TABLE (...) LEFT JOIN (...) approach.

This does not answer my own question, but solves the problem which, for me, was good enough.